# How do we handle questions based on cross faith?

Tags: discussion

Namaste, to all respected members!

For an example, this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37786/hindus-and-halal?noredirect=1#comment121355_37786):

> "Hindus and halal" [*It is not even a properly formatted question*].

It further talks about Halal Vegetarian food in description section:

> Is it OK for a Hindu to consume halal certified vegetarian items? There are vegetarian food items like spices and pickles that are certified like that.Should I ignore it or look for non-halal alternatives?
>
> I do understand there aren't any clear answer. My expectation is to just get some guidance as to how to approach the subject or some pointers that I can explore further.

So, how do we handle this question, which also require understanding of the term "Halal" from one of the Abrahamic religion. I suspect, that it is safe to answer this question, as in Hinduism we do not have any authentic scripture defining the term "Halal".

For that, do we require intervention of Islamic scholar providing proper understating of the term **Halal**?

Or, is it possible to answer based on general awareness and google search of the term?

Or, does this question required to be closed?

Or, this question will always be dangling on SE.Hinduism?

Any insight on this conundrum of cross faith question would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much of cross religion questions should we allow?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-much-of-cross-religion-questions-should-we-allow)