# How much of cross religion questions should we allow?

Tags: discussion, scope

In our FAQ post: [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/45/277), we have following suggestion:

> **Avoid asking cross religion questions**, I am just highlighting this out in bold because we want to avoid religion wars here, don't compare any other religion with Hinduism, stick to the topic, I would not post any examples for this, I hope people understand. Don't compare religions on good/bad parts, don't post questions if you've heard some cross religion rumors ...

So, as per this FAQ, we are supposed not to allow cross religions questions or questions that compares religions. But we have a tag for [other-religions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/other-religions) through which we sometimes compares the concepts of religions.

I think we need to determine the scope for the other/cross religion questions. Provide your feedback in the answer: how much of cross-religion questions we should allow or which types of questions should be allowed and which not.

Comment: I already asked the same question two months ago. https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1771/5212 Why is not answered but the same question is asked again?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Buddhism questions are special case as Stack Exchange has dedicated site for Buddhism Stack Exchange

Comment: [Related or duplicate?] [Questions asking whether Hinduism is unique with respect to a particular feature?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1712/93)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is comparison of a topic with other religions on-topic?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/is-comparison-of-a-topic-with-other-religions-on-topic)

Comment: ^ Though, I am not satisfied with the answer in above duplicate post.

Answer (score 1):

Every religion talks about mainly below things:

1. Rituals and Worship
2. Way of living life.
3. Philosophies on manifestation of the Universe
4. Nature of God

While rituals and worship ways may differ a lot. However rest other points can be compared.
For example, One can ask question on way of life:

> How remarrying is done in Hinduism like it can be done in [Islam after giving divorce](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/17186) ?

Example of asking questions on Philosophies:

> As per Christianity,
>
> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. He was in the beginning with God. All things were made through him, and without him was not any thing made that was made.
>
> Does Hinduism also has same concept of creation of universe?

One can also ask about nature of God, How much it differs from other religions or is it same. Example question on the same:

> As per Christianity,
> God said to Moses, “I am who I am.” And he said, “Say this to the people of Israel, ‘I am has sent me to you.’” Ref: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/17178
> Does Hinduism talk about nature of God, If yes, what it says? Is it same as per Christianity?

So, IMO as long as OP is particular about some practices existing in other religions, and want to understand existence of similar practices/philosophy in Hinduism, That should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with this:

> **Avoid asking cross religion questions**

^ This should be strictly followed without even space for `to compare the concepts of religions.` [As I discussed here before](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1729/93). Such questions should be asked in other SE sites like:

- History.SE
- Mythology.SE
- Skeptics.SE

Looks like we, community members, didn't follow the established scope which just made the `other-religions` tag end up with a lot of **off-topic posts**.

It is better to delete those posts now along with the tag `other-religions`.

Comment: Comparative religion is not on-topic on History, Mythology, or Skeptics. It's fine if you don't want the questions here, but you can't send them there.